# ¿ Como puedo ajustar el tamaño de un div automaticamente segun el tamaño de mi sidebar?

Tags: html, css

Veran tengo un sidebar que con un boton oculta el contenido de los menu y solo deja iconos,
mi problema es que al coloca el div donde iran el contenido de los menus este no se adapta al tamaño del sidebar es decir y yo presiono el boton para que muestre los nombre de los menus el div del contenido no se ajusta al espacio que el sidebar ocupa ..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

serian tan amables de ayudarme

Este es mi código HTML
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes colocar la estructura HTML y el código CSS, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no pienso transcribir el texto de tu imágen